# Why is the sound not working in Viber Desktop?

Tags: 14.04, viber

I'm using the Viber Desktop app

http://www.viber.com/en/products/linux

but when trying to make a call I can't hear the other person and they can't hear me. I opened the Sound Settings and the app didn't show as generating any sound.

Any help?

I'm on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Do you have any sound distortions?

Comment: yes, but it usually goes away after a few seconds

Comment: Yes but is there a fix for this because is really annoying when someone pick up right away?

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't a viber issue, as I get it sometimes with google voice too, also may I suggest you open a separate question and you'll probably get an answer here, I'm the only person who get's your messages and don't have the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was with the same problem. I fix it changing the "Audio Output" on Viber Settings>Audio & Video.

I hope this can solve your problem too.

Comment: nice!! had to switch from "HDMI" to "analog"

Comment: but there are still echoes of jitter heard when a call is being made or some notifications popup. Is there any solution to this?